# jQuery: question about children() function

Tags: jquery

how can I avoid this in jQuery:

> $(this).parents(".node-inner").children().children().children();

I tried:

> $(this).parents(".node-inner").children(".className");

but it doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: children looks only one level down (immediate children), use find as @Jørn Schou-Rode answered..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to search through the entire DOM subtree:

```
$(this).parents(".node-inner").find(".className");
```